# whoami produces different names on gcp terminal and local terminal

Tags: google-cloud-platform, command-line-interface

I've somehow ended up as two different users depending on where I'm connecting from. I think it's the result of my org creating users for different projects. If I execute `whoami` from my local terminal I'm `foo` but if I execute the command from the ssh.cloud terminal I'm `foo_foobar`.

I have a folder `projects` on the VM and I can see it from both terminals, but all the subfolders that belong to `foo` are not visible to `foo_foobar`. OK, I get it.

The biggest issue is that from my local terminal, as `foo` I can't pull from or push to a cloud repo.

So my ask is: does there exist a cli command that will let me connect as `foo_foobar` from my local? I've looked at my config with `gcloud config list` and the email and project ID are correct. Thanks

Comment: Instead of editing the title to SOLVED you are supposed to submit your answer, as an answer to the question, and then mark that as the correct answer. This makes your question useful to others and it will actually be solved.

Comment: got it - thanks and sorry

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use this ssh command: `gcloud compute ssh foo_foobar@foo-vm --zone us-west1-b`

The confusion was caused by the command provided in the dashboard from the SSH dropdown View gcloud command which is: `gcloud beta compute ssh` with no "foo_foobar@foo-vm". In other words the provided ssh command does not indicate that `username@instance_name` should be part of the command